# process excel file and save in mongoDb

Tags: excel, spring, mongodb, apache-poi, mongotemplate

I have a excel file as shown below which needs to be processed and saved in mongodb. i am using spring MongoTemplate for CRUD operations on mongoDB.

[image: the excel file to be processed]

The mongo db document is as shown below.

[image: Mongo document]

I know that we can process the excel using apache POI and I have iterated through the entire file and got the data printed on the console. But I am not clear on how to handle this in the best possible way.

how can I insert these data into mongoDB ?

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation? http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.0.M1/reference/html/#mongo-template.save-update-remove

Comment: yes i have the crud operations working in my app using mongoTemplate. but it is simple implementation which creates a document on insert. I am unclear on how to handle this excel in the data model showing above.

Comment: How you model your documents depends a lot on how you want to use your data. There is no "one true way" of modelling data.

Comment: yes, agreed. this is the model that fits my requirement.

Comment: Ok, so you have a model and you know how to insert it into MongoDB. What is your question then?

Comment: I can do simple insert. not complex inserts. also how do I process the excel to do those inserts.

Comment: Post some code of the code you have written. Also, what is a complex insert?

Comment: @Martin. I think "complex insert" means inserting a blob or "BSON" in MongoDB.